# Hangman won't take repeating letters in Java.

Tags: java

With my Java program. It takes a users char and sees if it's in a random word. However, if the char is in the word more than once, my program won't detect the char in the word after the char's first appearance. How can I fix the method below so that it will. Thank you in advance.

```
public Boolean guessChar(char guess){
   for(int index = 0; index < hiddenWord.length; index++){
        if(guess == hiddenWord[index]){
           userWord[index] = guess;
           return true;
         }
       }

        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Why would you need to find all of the characters? It seems you are just checking if the char appears at least once, in which case your code is fine.

Comment: Use a `continue` keyword, and set a condition to true if something is there. That way it will finish the entire loop, and then return the condition. Also, `boolean` should be lowercase; you're returning a data type.

Answer (score 1):

A quick modification based on your code is as follow:

```
public Boolean guessChar(char guess){
    boolean result = false;
    for(int index = 0; index < hiddenWord.length; index++){
        if(guess == hiddenWord[index]){
            userWord[index] = guess;
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Currently your `for` loop will not loop over all the characters since the method returns if the first matching character is found.

To fix this, you can introduce a boolean value (`result`) with default value `false`. If a matching character is found, you update this variable to `true`, and after looping over all the characters, your method returns `result`.